Problems removing non-linear terms from an expression
Using the code provided in the answer here, I want to remove nonlinear terms in my mathematica code.
I do it with the function:
veclist = {\[Delta]a, \[Delta]b, \[Delta]c}
linearizeExpression[exp_, veclst_] :=
  Total[Map[If[Total[Exponent[#, veclst]] > 1, Nothing, #] &, 
    MonomialList[exp]]];

But here I see a peculiar bug:
veclist = {\[Delta]a, \[Delta]b, \[Delta]c}
linearizeExpression[exp_, veclst_] :=
  Total[Map[If[Total[Exponent[#, veclst]] > 1, Nothing, #] &, 
    MonomialList[exp]]];
linearizeExpression[\[Delta]c + \[Delta]a*\[Delta]c, veclist]
linearizeExpression[\[Delta]c + \[Gamma]a*\[Delta]a*\[Delta]c, veclist]
linearizeExpression[\[Delta]c + \[Gamma]a^(
   1/2)*\[Delta]a*\[Delta]c, veclist]

If I add an extra variable, in the first two examples the code can handle it. But in the third example, if I raise that variable to the square-root power, I get a bug.
Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

From the help of "MomominalLis"t:
MonomialList[poly] gives the list of all monomials in the polynomial poly
Therefore, it only works with polynomials. Now look what you get from your expression:
exp = \[Delta]c + \[Gamma]a^(1/2)*\[Delta]a*\[Delta]c;
MonomialList[exp]


Now if you feed this to "Exponent":
Exponent[exp, veclst]

0


Just make the following change:
linearizeExpression[exp_, veclst_] := 
Total[Map[If[Total[Exponent[#, veclst]] > 1, Nothing, #] &, 
MonomialList[exp, veclst]]];

The issue arises because the expression involves a term where one of the symbols is raised to a fractional exponent. MonomialList is designed to work with polynomials, and this term does not qualify as a polynomial due to the fractional exponent. As a result, MonomialList cannot return the monomials unless you specify the list of variables to be considered. Not all variables in the expression are appropriate for defining a polynomial, which is why the function requires clarification in this case.
Another alternative is to use CoefficientRules and FromCoefficientRules:
linearizeExpression[expr_, veclst_] := 
FromCoefficientRules[Select[CoefficientRules[expr, veclst], 
Count[#[[1]], 1] == 1 &], veclst]

